# Solution for this equation

Tags: functions, data-analysis

I have been working on a random function I found with some data I simulated and was wondering if anyone has an idea how to, or perhaps can even find a solution for it. The relationship is: 
$$
f(x) = 2\cdot f(4x) 
$$
I have no idea if it's even possible to find an explicit solution for f(x) from this, on the other hand, maybe it's really easy, but I am completely stumped. Anyone want to have a go?

Comment: Is $f\colon \Bbb R\rightarrow \Bbb R$ an arbitrary function satisfying $f(x)=2f(4x)$? Or is it continuous? Or is it an integer valued function?

Comment: Well I modelled the temperature of particles in a container. The velocities were randomised by a normal distribution centred around 0 with a variance of k*300/1e-10.
k being Boltzmann's constant.
x in the function is actually N, the amount of particles in the container which I used 
10 000, 20 000, 40 000, ... 
2 560 000

Comment: I did this many times and found that f(N) = 2f(4N) pretty precisely.

Comment: So you know much more. Mathematically, even $f\equiv 0$ satisfies your functional equation, so you should impose more senisitve conditions.

Comment: What sort of conditions should i impose, not really that great at maths hehe

Comment: Come on, if I read Boltzmann, I suppose you know some physics. Then use reasonable assumptions from physics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility that comes straight to my mind is $f(x)=|x|^{-1/2}$ (for $x\neq0$). Then
$$
f(4x)=\frac{1}{|4x|^{1/2}}=\frac{1}{2}f(x)
$$
as you desire.

More generally, you can look for homogeneous functions of degree $-1/2$, i.e. functions $h(x)$ that satisfy
$$
h(\lambda x)=\lambda^{-1/2}h(x)
$$
for any $\lambda>0$ and then take $\lambda=4$.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If $f \in \mathcal{C}([0,\alpha[)$ where $\alpha>0$.

We have :

$$\forall x \in [0,\alpha[, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, f(x) = f(x/4)/2 = f(x/16)/4 =... = f(x/4^n)/2^n $$ then by continuity $\forall x \in [0,\alpha[, f(x) = 0$.

Well it might not answer your expectations though.